# React Native Searchable Dropdown shows blank fields

Tags: react-native

I 'm trying to use Searchable Dropdown to show an array of objects:

```
<SearchableDropdown
           style={{height:'100%'}}
          onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
          
          onItemSelect={(item) => this.sendrequest(JSON.stringify(item.title))}
         
          containerStyle={{padding: 5}}
       
          textInputStyle={{
            
            padding: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            backgroundColor: '#FAF7F6',
          }}
          itemStyle={{
            
            padding: 10,
            height:50,
            marginTop: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#FAF9F8',
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
          itemTextStyle={{
           
            color: '#222',
          }}
          itemsContainerStyle={{
            
            maxHeight: '60%',
          }}
          items={this.state.hospitals}
          defaultIndex={1}
          placeholder="placeholder"
          
          resetValue={false}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          
        />
```

Following is my "this.state.hospitals"

```
"hospitals": [
        {
            "title": "Holy Family Hospital Rawalpindi",
            "distance": "71.45372179866516"
        },
        {
            "title": "Fauji Foundation Hospital Islamabad",
            "distance": "62.242918533343705"
        },
        {
            "title": "PIMS Hospital Islamabad",
            "distance": "80.0576175928936"
        }
```

I want the titles to be displayed in the dropdown but it shows nothing. Everything else works corectly, but there are just blank fields to scroll through. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: packageName that you're using for  <SearchableDropdown /> component?

Comment: this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown? @Jawad

Comment: @LakshmanKambam Thanks for replying, and yes I'm using the same package with the same version that you mentioned.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: given answer and let me know if you need any help doing same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchableDropdown` doesn't have any custom prop to handle keyName of dataObject inside array.

[image]

you're sending key as `title` in object but it's access keyName as `name`. so you need to format your data before sending it as items to that component

```
let formatHospitalsData = [...this.state.hospitals];
formatHospitalsData = formatHospitalsData.map((item) => {
   return {
      distance: item.distance,
      name: item.title
   }
});
```

after replacing the key, send it to `SearchableDropdown` Component

```
[
    {
        "name": "Holy Family Hospital Rawalpindi",
        "distance": "71.45372179866516"
    },
    {
        "name": "Fauji Foundation Hospital Islamabad",
        "distance": "62.242918533343705"
    },
    {
        "name": "PIMS Hospital Islamabad",
        "distance": "80.0576175928936"
    }
]
```

Comment: HEYY.. Thank you SO much..!!! It worked like a charm, you're the best.

Comment: sure, anytime. can you mark it as answer @JawadJahangir